# Show Splash-Like Screen JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to show a splash like screen using JQuery. I have my #load div which is the splash, then I have a class put on my body (#body) that I want to fade in after the splash. I tried writing a script, but it seems to happen to fast, and things don't work the way I described.

```
   $(function() {
$('#load').fadeIn(3000).fadeIn(0);
     $('#load').addClass("none");
    $('#body').removeClass("none");
 });
```

Is there a better way to write this? I didn't know where to put the FadeIn() at..

I do NOT want #body to show while the #load is showing.

Comment: More code (or even better, a demo on http://jsfiddle.net) would be very helpful in answering this.

Answer (score 0):

Well `fadeIn(0)` is gonna zip it in! Change it to `$('#load').fadeIn(5000);`

Comment: That is nice! I do not want #body to show while #load is showing.. Did I do that right?